# Find EditText in a complex layout

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an Android UI layout that is rather complex (it has a lot added to it dynamically depending on business rules).

One part of the UI has a LinearLayout which contains another layout which contains an EditText. Sometimes there is another LinearLayout in the base layout with the edit text in - it looks like this

```
LinearLayout
|
+-EditText
|
+-LinearLayout
| |
| +-EditText
+-EditText
|
+-LinearLayout
| |
| +-LinearLayout
| | |
| | +-EditText
| +-EditText
```

And so on

Currently, I have a pile of loops in a method that check if it's LinearLayout, then checks if the next Child is an EditText or a LinearLayout. If it's another LinearLayout then it creates another loop, checks if there is an EditText and so on. It gets messy.

Is there a way in LINQ (or something similar) that I can iterate through an entire LinearLayout in order to pick out the EditText widgets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a way in LINQ as you've requested, and am not sure how you're looping in code, but a few years back I had a similar need, and created a class that will iterate every view, including deeply nested views.

The output string displays the full hierarchy, including children, grandchildren, etc. with appropriate indentations. Of course, you can modify the code to look for a specific view type and act on it, such as:

```
if (vChild is EditText) vChild.Enabled = false;
```

Hope this helps!

```
public class IterateView {
    // Iterate a view and all children recursively and generate a visual hierarchy

    #region Example Usage
    // //OnCreate()...
    // SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyLayout);
    // RelativeLayout view = FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.MyRelativeLayoutView);
    // IterateView iv = new IterateView();
    // iv.Iterate(view);
    // string s = iv.OutputString;
    #endregion

    private readonly StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    private const string PADDING_STRING = "  ";
    private string sPadding = "";
    public string OutputString { get; private set; }

    public void Iterate(View view) {
        if (view is ViewGroup)
            IterateViewChildren(view);
        else
            sb.AppendLine(sPadding + view.GetType().Name);
        OutputString = sb.ToString();
    }

    private void IterateViewChildren(View view) {
        if (view is ViewGroup) {
            sb.AppendLine(sPadding + view.GetType().Name + " (ViewGroup)");
            sPadding += PADDING_STRING;
            ViewGroup vGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
            for (int i = 0; i < vGroup.ChildCount; i++) {
                if (!(vGroup.GetChildAt(i) is ViewGroup))
                    sb.AppendLine(sPadding + vGroup.GetChildAt(i).GetType().Name);
                View vChild = vGroup.GetChildAt(i);
                IterateViewChildren(vChild);
            }
            // Remove padding after iterating children to get us back to where we need to be
            sPadding = sPadding.Remove(sPadding.Length - PADDING_STRING.Length);
        }
    }
}
```